# Dimensional regularization and expansion of gamma function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, dimensional-regularization

In my calculations, I used dimensional regularization, i.e. replace $d\rightarrow d-\epsilon$ and calculated the divergent integral. Then, I would like to expand the answer into seriers by $\epsilon$ around $\epsilon=0$. But I obtained strange result. I start from the following integral (where I denote $d=3-\epsilon$):
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}dp\frac{p^2}{p^2+m^2}$$
which is divergent. Then, I have calculated the integral
$$ I(\epsilon)=\int_{0}^{\infty}dp\frac{p^{d-1}}{p^2+m^2}=\frac{m^{d-2}}{2}\Gamma(d/2)\Gamma(1-d/2)$$
which is convergent for $d<2$. Also, I also have integral over angles, which is in $d$-dimensional case can be written as
$$\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d)}.$$
So, my final answer is
$$I(\epsilon)\propto\Gamma(\epsilon/2-1/2)$$
Using Wolfram Mathematia, I find the expansion around $\epsilon=0$. My expectation was that the divergence of my integral will be appear like a pole, $1/\epsilon$. But from the expansion I see no one singular term.

Comment: I have seen conventions in dim. reg. using both $d=4-2\epsilon$ and $d=4-\epsilon$, but I rarely see one ever use $d=3-\epsilon$. I'm assuming you're computing a 2+1 dimensional integral rather than a 3+1?

Comment: @Triatticus, yes. The question is about DimReg in $2+1$ or in $2n+1$

Comment: I see, then as you've answered that is the source of your issue, glad you sorted it out quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to present the answer.

DimReg replaces any even divergnces (log, quadratic, etc.) by pole $1/\epsilon$. For any odd divergence, DimReg doesn't give the correct answer. This problem can be solved by PDS (Power Divergence Substruction) which is discussed in the following [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037026939800210X?via%3Dihub).